# performance - String operation with Java to get most repeated char

Tags: java, string, performance, notation

It is a [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) problem.

My String can contain many characters, I need to find out the most repeated character in my string.

> Ex: str="sample string contains aaaaaaaaaa #12";
>   Here most repeated char is 'a'

**My Code: (algorithm)**

> 1. Initialized 2D array with size 127 (ASCII) chars. arr[127][2]
> 2. Parsed the string, incrementing the ASCII index of array with respective values.

```
>        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
>           arr[str.charAt(1)][1] += 1;
```

> 1. Finally, going through the array to find out the max value of arr[x][1]

This problem, taking `O(n)` to solve it.

I am looking for better performance, when the string size is very huge.

Thanks!

Comment: How would you ever do better than O(n)? In the worst case you must check every character in the string.

Comment: Why is this a two-dimensional array? It seems like you only ever use `arr[...][1]`, never `arr[...][0]`. Also, surely by `arr[i+1][1] += 1` you must mean `arr[str.charCodeAt(i)][1] += 1`?

Comment: You could short-circuit it by stopping when the most-repeated character's hits minus the second most hits is more than the remaining number of characters, otherwise you are going have to iterate the whole string.  However the overhead of keeping track of the two most common letters may be more that the short-circuit.

Comment: @DStanley - unless there is something special about the strings, it *will* be more.

Comment: Even if you short circuit and even if the structure of the strings is favourable on average, it's still O(n). Being forced to traverse any fixed proportion of a string (in this case half) is always O(n) cost.

Comment: @ruakh: thanks, Yes i have put here wrongly, I am updating it. that was the correct one

Answer (score 2):

I can imagine an algorithm something like Boyers-Moore for string matching. One you've identified a repeated sequence of *n* characters, then to check if a sequence starting at position *i* is longer, then you only need to check position *i+n* to see if it's the same character as at position *i*. If it is not, then you start checking at position *i+1*; if it is, then you start looping over the characters between those two points to see if they're all the same. If you do this right, you can end up skipping over a lot of the string. Worst-case, it's still O(n), as it must be, but best-case you can skip a lot.

As far as the space requirement:  just keep track of the longest run length, and the character (or the starting position.) You don't need the 2-D array.

Comment: I think you are trying to solve a different problem.  The algorithm in the question is simply counting the number of occurrences of each character.  Your sketched algorithm is looking for the longest run of any single character.

Comment: Urk. You're right. Don't know I managed to miss the mark so badly on this one!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get better TIMED efficiency, because there's no way other than checking every character (that I can think of), but you may be able to get better STORAGE efficiency by using any list based data structure that lets you create new nodes on the fly. That way you can just add a new element to the list every time you see a character not already in the list, or just increase the count of an element already in the list. You may not need 127 unique characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in O(n) time using the same approach except every time you update a value check if it's larger than the current largest value. If it is set it as the new largest value and continue. When you're done the current largest will be the largest value (you can store the index or something that way you can print out the character at the end).

In your case you scan the string in O(n) but then you scan the array at the end, if you do it this way you mitigate the final array scan on the array of ASCII values you have.

Comment: This optimization works for short strings (<<128), but not for long ones (>> 128).

Comment: @StephenC Do you mean characters with ascii values higher than 128? If so you can use a hashmap instead to keep track of ONLY characters that occur.

Comment: No that's not what I mean.  Suppose L == string length >> 128.  Now the cost of L times `if array[i] > largest then largest = array[i]` is going to be more than the cost of scanning / testing 128 array cells.  The OP *says* that he wants to optimize for really large strings.